# change total amount in tree view odoo invoice

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I want to change decimal precision of total in tree view Invoice

For Example:

> FROM **252.301.25** ==>  TO This **253.301.250**

In footer of tree view Invoice
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto 
   `Settings -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy` to change decimal precision in odoo. Refer this [link](http://netjunky.net/change-odoo-decimal-precision-configuration/) for more details.
You can also use digits in field declaration for this.

```
 ` total = fields.float('Total ', digits=(16,4))`
```

you can give the value according to your need,if you need 1.000 change it to (16,3) if needed 1.00 then change it to (16,2).